# Problems forming a dictionary from values in two different dictionaries

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have two dictionaries:

```
y = {0:[345, 543], 1: [657, 789], 2: [867, 213]}
x = {867: [1,6], 657: [1,4], 213: [1,7], 345: [1, 2], 543: [1, 3], 789: [1, 5]}
```

I would like to create a third dictionary that replaces the value lists in dictionary `y` with the corresponding list values from dictionary `x`. So ultimately I'd like to end up with:

```
z = {0: [[1,2],[1,3]], 1:[[1,4],[1,5]], 2:[[1,6],[1,7]]}
```

I'm honestly not sure where to even begin. Is there perhaps a module that I'm missing that would make this easier?

Comment: Defining what exactly *"corresponding*" means to you in this context will most likely get you one step closer to a solution.

Comment: This can be done in one line - do you know how to iterate over a dictionary? How to iterate over a list? How to get items from a dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a dict comprehension:

```
z = {k:[x[vi][:] for vi in v] for k,v in y.items()}
```

That is:

A map of k to [a list of copies of the values in x corresponding to keys from v], for each item k,v in the dict y.

(Accepting suggestion from jonrsharpe)

Comment: I'd suggest `x[vi][:]` to avoid referencing issues.

Comment: Thanks! I had a sneaky suspicion that I was missing something like this. I'm a bit new to Python, and I was trying different combinations of iterations, but I was sure that there was a better way. I appreciate the help!